# Nokogiri truncating HTML for some pages, not others

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

We are using Nokogiri to parse data from iTunes. On some pages, it works. On others, it fails and truncates the page mysteriously.

Our code:

```
# Get iTunes HTML for app bundle
itunes_url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app-bundle/id918236019'
uri = URI.parse itunes_url
http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
resp = http.request req

# Covnert HTML into XML for parsing
bundle_xml = Nokogiri.XML resp.body
bundle_xml.remove_namespaces!

#puts "ERRORS: #{bundle_xml.errors}"

puts "ORIGINAL\n=============\n#{resp.body}\n\n\n\n============="
puts "NOKO\n=============\n#{bundle_xml}"
```

Even though errors are returned for other iTunes pages, Nokogiri is able to parse the page properly. Basically, most of the elements after a certain element are removed mysteriously by Nokogiri.

Resp.body output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/33ecfe82e3d22a39375a

Nokogiri output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7622ef92bf430889b9f4

```
i18n (0.6.11, 0.6.9, 0.6.5, 0.6.4, 0.6.1)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.4, 2.2.1)
json (1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.7.7, 1.5.5)
kgio (2.8.1, 2.8.0)
mail (2.4.4)
mime (0.4.0, 0.2.0, 0.1)
mime-types (1.25.1, 1.25, 1.24, 1.23, 1.21)
mini_portile (0.6.0, 0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.1)
minitest (2.5.1)
mongo (1.10.0, 1.9.2, 1.9.1)
mongo_mapper (0.12.0)
mongoid (3.1.6)
moped (1.5.2, 1.5.1)
multi_json (1.10.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.0, 1.8.4, 1.8.2, 1.8.0, 1.7.9, 1.7.7, 1.6.1)
mysql2 (0.3.16, 0.3.15)
newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229, 3.7.3.204, 3.7.2.192, 3.6.6.147)
nokogiri (1.6.1, 1.6.0)
```

Comment: Are you *sure* it's Nokogiri truncating? perhaps `resp.body` is incomplete.

Comment: Yes, the output of resp.body has more than bundle_xml.

Comment: What's the difference? Do you have samples to show?

Comment: @MarkThomas just updated the answer with samples. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using one of the HTTP libraries, like Ruby's own OpenURI, HTTParty, Curb or Typhoeus. They'll handle redirects for you automatically, plus will require less code than trying to write this using Net::HTTP. Net::HTTP is useful but it's a building block that others have already used to implement well tested wheels.

Comment: @theTinMan do you mean to fetch the HTML or to parse the HTML? our challenge right now is in parsing the HTML.

Comment: To fetch the HTML. BTW, you're using off-site examples of the HTML and Nokogiri output, which is NOT how you should supply either. You should supply minimal examples in your question, so people trying to answer don't have to chase down the information necessary to help you.

Answer (score 0):

By trying this myself, I think I see the problem. You're parsing an HTML response.

Change

```
bundle_xml = Nokogiri.XML resp.body
```

to:

```
bundle_xml = Nokogiri.HTML resp.body
```

and see if this works for you.

The HTML parser is much more lenient and handles missing closing tags, etc.

Comment: Yes, it does. What version of Nokogiri and libxml2 do you have?

Comment: Hmm, sorry but the last comment didn't get posted yesterday. The question has been updated with the version of Nokogiri and related gems.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML has invalid markup. Nokogiri says:

```
>> @doc.errors
[
    [0] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>,
    [1] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: no name>,
    [2] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag nav invalid>
]
```

That can make content disappear as Nokogiri attempts to fix up the HTML to make it usable.